# The basic installation of firebase package in WIX project doesn't work

Tags: firebase, velo

I installed firebase v-5.8.2 package through WIX's package manager.  The installation process doesn't have any problem per se.  After installation, I added "import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'", without any other code.  When I run the project, it gave error message "can not find module 'fs'"

In the wix's forum, seems that someone had success experience with an earlier firebase version.  Wondering if the v-5.8.2 has some problem with WIX.

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

"can not find module 'fs'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing it on a backend .jsw file, right?

NPM modules can only be imported on backend files and not on your page code.

You can export the functions from a backend file like below:

```
//serverSide.jsw

import firebase from 'firebase';

var app = require('firebase');

export function backendModule() {
        //Your backend function code here
}
```

Then import the function on the frontend page code like below:

```
import {backendModule} from 'backend/serverSide.jsw';

$w.onReady(function () {
    //TODO: write your page related code here...

});
```

If you are already importing on the backend file then try this below

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```